# How to retrieve specific data from laravel database in WHMCS?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using WHMCS and i want to retrieve dedicated IP, but i am unable to do, can anyone please help,

This is my code.

```
$serviceid = 50
$ip = Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('id',$serviceid)->select('dedicatedip')->get();
print_r($ip);
```

But output just comes out as Array ( ).

I want to get data on `dedicatedip`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have re-written the code and put down as answer, you can substitute your requirement in case you want to retrieve something from the database.

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution.

```
$table = Capsule::table('tblhosting')->where('id',$params['serviceid'])->get();
            $hosting_details = (array) $res[0];
            $dedicatedip = $hosting_details['dedicatedip'];
            print_r($dedicatedip);
```

Comment: you should bind your model to its table by $table

Comment: @OMR, done. tho res was relevant to my code, but i can see why you suggest that.